# SQL: How to (WHERE) column (SUM) by caption or index?

Tags: sql, where-clause

How do I make a condition (WHERE) then a column caption or index which is contained some functions like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1 AS [COLUMN_1_Val], 
COLUMN_2 AS [COLUMN_2_Val], 
SUM(A+B-C-D)*E*F/G -SUM(H-I)*K/L AS [My_Complicated_Function], 
COLUMN_3 AS [COLUMN_3_Val]

WHERE [My_Complicated_Function]>0
```

How do I call my function column in WHERE clause or even by its index like (WHERE columnindex(2)>0)

Comment: It depends on DBMS features available. What is your DBMS?

Comment: No `FROM` clause?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your first part in subquery

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT COLUMN_1 AS [COLUMN_1_Val], 
   COLUMN_2 AS [COLUMN_2_Val], 
   SUM(A+B-C-D)*E*F/G -SUM(H-I)*K/L AS [My_Complicated_Function], 
   COLUMN_3 AS [COLUMN_3_Val]
   FROM ... 
)
WHERE [My_Complicated_Function]>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say ,you have a function func_Sum as follows,

```
create function func_Sum  
(  
 @Num int   
)  
returns int 
as  
begin 
return(select @Num+@Num)  
end
```

now you can use this function in where clause like this,

```
SELECT 1 AS [COLUMN_1_Val], 
2 AS [COLUMN_2_Val], 
TEST.dbo.func_Sum(5) AS [my_func], 
5 AS [COLUMN_3_Val]
WHERE TEST.dbo.func_Sum(5) >0
```

Comment: highly technical way @Shafiqul Bari Sadman :) thanks